# Check if row of a dataframe is equal to a row of another disregarding NA values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data.frames.

df1 may have several rows which never contain NAs and it looks like:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
1    1    2    1
2    1    2    3
3    1    2    1
1    2    2    2
```

while df2 has always one row that may contain NAs and it looks like this:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
1    NA   2    NA
```

I am looking for a way to test for each line of df1 if df2 is equal to that line diregarding all values that are NA. After the check for the example above I expect to get:

```
TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

So far I have tried several combinations of all() and which() but I haven't found an efficient solution.

Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am interested in efficiency too so, ideally, I would like to avoid a loop within a loop checking if the value of the current column is NA

Comment: `t( apply( df1, 1 , function(x) all( x == df2[1,] | is.na(df2[1,] ) ) ) )`

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
m1 <- t(df1)
v1 <- unlist(df2)
m1[is.na(v1)] <- NA
colSums(m1==v1|is.na(m1))==ncol(m1)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```